# Random number generation within Compile and Parallelization->True

Tags: parallelization, random, compile

According to this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) `RandomChoice` is a compilable function.
I use it to generate random numbers in a compiled function with parallelization enabled.

I wrote another variant of my program where I generate these random numbers outside of the compiled function and then use the generated array as an input argument of the compiled function.

Now it seems that when computing moments of my random trajectories with the parallelized compiled function (where the random numbers are generated within `Compile`), the outcome of the averaged result for a fixed number of steps is always the same as if it always uses the same sequence of random numbers.

On the other hand, if I generate the random numbers outside of `Compile` the averaged result fluctuates when repeating the calculation for a fixed number of steps as expected.

Anybody has a clue of what could be going on in the parallelized version of the program? Is it maybe due to the fact that if I generate the random numbers via `Compile` in parallel, the sequence of random numbers per thread is the same on all threads? And if yes, how would I avoid this but still use the parallelization capabilities of `Compile`?

Thank you for your help!

**[Edit]**

I am aware of this [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html) in the documentation, but cannot apply it. What I want is not to predefine a seed, but genuinely independent random number generation on each thread when calling the parallelized compiled function.

**[Edit2]**

Ok, now I found the culprit. Probably it is a trivial error which I don't see?

If I execute the following in a single code block

```
x0 = Table[{RandomVariate[pdf1], RandomVariate[pdf2]}, {nTraj}];
list = av[cf[x0, nSteps], rangeav];
```

then `list` remains almost the same after several runs of the code block.

If I execute the commands in two code blocks, i.e.

```
x0 = Table[{RandomVariate[pdf1], RandomVariate[pdf2]}, {nTraj}];
```

and subsequently

```
list = av[cf[x0, nSteps], rangeav];
```

then it behaves as supposed and changes drastically after each run of the code blocks. I am confused now whether this is normal behavior or not?

So sometimes it seems to take over the new argument `x0` (which is updated correctly) and sometimes it seems to be stuck and then it uses the same random numbers within `Compile`. The random number generation, however, does not depend on `x0` (`x0` is only used to pre-allocate an array `x`).

Or in other words, it cannot update the argument `x0` and create a different set of random numbers within `Compile` at the same time.

**[Edit3]**

As outlined in the comments, I think this behavior is a bug. To make the code lines now completely unrelated, I define a symbolic continous pdf by

```
pdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Sqrt[2]/Pi/(1 + x^4), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

The specific appearence of the pdf doesn't matter. Now if I call

```
RandomVariate[pdf];
list = av[cf[x0, nSteps], rangeav];
```

in the same code block and have `Parallelization->True` in the compiled function `cf` then only the sequence of results for the different threads changes for different runs, so that the position of the sublists are interchanged but the overall `list` gives the same result for different runs.

However, if I call

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.,1.]];
list = av[cf[x0, nSteps], rangeav];
```

Then the sublists in `list` are created anew every time I run the code block.

So it seems as if `RandomVariate[pdf]` of a pre-defined pdf triggers the seed of a compiled function (which itself generates random numbers) if it is called in the same code block. If one calls `RandomVariate[pdf]` in a separate code block everything is fine again.

Very, very strange.

Now the question remains whether this kind of behaviour is reproducable in a minimal working example or appears only in the specific case of my compiled function that I use.

**[Edit4]**

Here is a minimal working example that produces the same issue on my machine with MMA 11.3

```
(*Define pdf*)
pdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Sqrt[2]/Pi/(1 + x^4), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

(*Define compiled funcion*)
cf := Compile[{{nSteps, _Integer, 0}},
   Block[{rand},
    (*Random number generation*)        
    rand = RandomChoice[{1./6, 1./6, 2./3} -> {Sqrt[3.], -Sqrt[3.], 
        0.}, {nSteps}];
    rand], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Now investigate the two cases (execute the two lines in one code block respectively):

```
list=Table[RandomVariate[pdf];
                cf[Table[10, {$ProcessorCount}]], {2}];
```

gives output

```
{{{1.73205, -1.73205, 1.73205, 1.73205, 0., 1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 
       1.73205}, {0., -1.73205, 1.73205, 0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 
       0.}, {0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
       1.73205, 0., 0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0.}}, {{1.73205, -1.73205, 
       1.73205, 1.73205, 0., 1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 1.73205}, {0., 0., 0., 
       1.73205, 0., 0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., -1.73205, 1.73205, 0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 
       0., 0., 0.}}}
```

and

```
list=Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1.]];
                 cf[Table[10, {$ProcessorCount}]], {2}]
```

gives output

```
{{{0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {1.73205, 0., 
       1.73205, 1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., -1.73205, -1.73205,
        0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 1.73205, 0.}, {1.73205, -1.73205, 0., 
       0., 0., 0., -1.73205, 0., 0., 0.}}, {{0., -1.73205, 0., -1.73205, 
       0., 1.73205, 1.73205, -1.73205, 0., 1.73205}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.73205, 1.73205, 0.,
        0.}, {1.73205, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}}
```

Now compare `list[[1]]` with `list[[2]]` for the two code blocks. With the second code block the random numbers are generated anew each time the command is executed. With the first code block only the sublists are interchanged, but the total `list[[1]]` and `list[[2]]` remains the same.

Or in shorter and possibly more convenient form:

```
(*Function for comparison of parts of list*)
same[{a_, b__}] := SameQ[a, b]
```

and then

```
m = 10;
list = Table[RandomVariate[pdf];
   cf[Table[10, {$ProcessorCount}]], {m}];
same[Map[Sort, list]]
```

which gives `True` and

```
m = 10;
list = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1.]];
   cf[Table[10, {$ProcessorCount}]], {m}];
same[Map[Sort, list]]
```

which gives `False`.

Comment: My suggestion would be to write your RNG-using `Compile` function to take a second argument for a seed or something like that, then pass in a set of random seeds. On the other hand without some code to work with it'll be hard to debug fully for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is sort of strange because I can just let MMA give the random numbers as an output and they differ for the different threads. I wonder what leads then to this strange behavior. Mhh

Comment: @b3m2a1: See my [Edit2] it has to do with some outside definitions which are then passed over to the compiled function as an argument.

Comment: I think we'll need a more complete sense of your code to understand what's going on. Can you make a minimum working example with all functions defined? (e.g. `af`, `pdf1`, etc.)

Comment: The problem is that the whole computation is a little bit long and consists of different parts. I will try to come up with a simple example which is shorter tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. That (a simple example that demonstrates the problem) is what we mean by a minimum working example.

Comment: You could try seeding the random number generator based on the process id or kernel id of each kernel to make them behave differently, e.g. `SeedRandom[$KernelID]` or`SeedRandom[$ProcessID]`.

Comment: I tried it with the different seeds but it didn't resolve the problem. It seems to be a bug to me. If I execute a single code block where the first line calls `RandomVariate[pdf]` of a pre-defined `ProbabilityDistribution` it has an impact on the compiled function even if this first line isn't used as an input argument of this function (i.e. the code lines are completely unrelated). However, the bug appears only if `RandomVariate` acts on a pre-defined `ProbabilityDistribution`. If I use `NormalDistribution` within `RandomVariate` it works fine again. Very, very strange I have to say.

Comment: See my [Edit3], still need to come up with a minimal example though. However, I think it is clearly a bug now :(

Comment: @b3m2a1: I added a minimal working example in my [Edit4].